# Possible to sort Labels in FlowlayoutPanel

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, label, flowlayoutpanel

I have created a `FlowLayoutPanel` where `labels` are added dynamically, the label data is taken from a `datagridview`. Is it possible to sort those labels using a `Date` `column` from the `datagridview`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flow layout panel will keep it's child controls in the order that they are added to it.
This means that you can't sort the controls on it.
Your only options are either to remove all the labels and add then in a different order, or to use a regular panel and then sort the existing label by changing the location property of all the labels.
The first option is, of course, much easier.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to order items of any container using the SetChildIndex method.

Here is an example of how to move an item up one place:

```
 myControl.Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(
     myControl,  myControl.Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(myControl) - 1)
```